Proxy ARP between Ubuntu and Raspberry
I have a not so new PC on which I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS. It does not have WiFi connectivity, and I do not have a wired internet connection. Therefore, I would like to endow it an internet access by means of a wired Ethernet connection with a Raspberry Pi, which connects to a WiFi hotspot.
The Raspberry has Raspberry Pi OS Bookworm, and it gets the IP dynamically on the wlan0 interface. Instead, on its Ethernet eth0 interface I set the static IP 172.16.10.105 and subnet mask 255.255.255.0.
On the other hand, the Ethernet interface enp4s0 on the old PC is set with the static IP 172.16.10.104, subnet mask 255.255.255.0, and gateway 172.16.10.105 (this is the IP of the eth0 interface of the Raspberry). To realize the bridge, I enable the IP forwarding by uncommenting the line:
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
in the file /etc/sysctl.conf, and I used parprouted as follows:
sudo parprouted -d eth0 wlan0
To monitor what happens on the eth0 interface of the Raspberry, I ran:
sudo tcpdump --interface eth0
The ping from the old PC to the Raspberry is ok, but when I try to access internet from the old PC (as an example, with curl https://stackoverflow.com) it fails, and both tcpdump and parprouted seem to indicate that the Raspberry did not receive anything. Here you can find the output of both tcpdump and parprouted (I just substituted a few IP and MAC addresses as a caution):
log files
They recorded the activity due to the ping, but they recorded nothing when I run the curl command. What am I missing? Thanks a lot.

This is a routing configuration problem on the Raspberry Pi that has Bookworm OS. You are configuring your Ubuntu PC with a static IP and a gateway address that is the Raspberry Pi. Your network configuration dictates that it's up to the Raspberry Pi to handle the traffic from the Ubuntu PC and route accordingly. Therefore, this is considered off-topic since you have an IP on the Ubuntu and you can ping your gateway.

Thanks for your reply. What I should do?

Ask the question at U&L.  Detail your intentions, setup, problem, and configuration.

Thanks! I proceed in this way
